# Setting vars in a contextvars.Context directly

Tags: python, python-contextvars

I want to call some function in a separate [contextvars.Context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.Context), with some variables in this context set by the caller:

```
def call_with_context(var, callback, **cb_kw):
    context = contextvars.copy_context()
    context.set('var', var)  # not possible
    context.run(callback, **cb_kw)
```

so that the callback and any code called from it would be able to access `var` via [`contextvars.copy_context()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.copy_context), but it looks like there is no API to do this, by design of `contextvars.Context`, and the only way to do this is to make a wrapper that sets the var via [`ContextVar.set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.ContextVar.set) and calls the callback, and call *that* wrapper via [`context.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.Context.run), is this the only way to implement this or am I missing something (maybe the `contextvars` design just requires doing some of this differently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after checking a suggested related question I've found that this is as simple as

```
context.run(var.set, 'var')
```

This seems to be working as intended.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an answer to why context vars can't be assigned directly to an explicitly instatiated context without using `run` and a callback?